# PHP 7 / C get value from HashTable

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I'm trying to overwrite and old extension from PHP 5.4 to PHP 7. In the old code there is a function `double get_arr_value(char *key, HashTable *table)` which returns (at least it should) value of the array as double. The definition is something like this:

```
double get_arr_value(char *key, HashTable *table) {
     double val;
     zend_string *zend_key = zend_string_init(key, 3, 0);

     if (zend_hash_exists(table, zend_key)) {
         zval *zv_dest = zend_hash_find(table, zend_key);

         if (zv_dest != NULL) {
             int type = Z_TYPE_P(zv_dest);

             if(type == IS_DOUBLE) {
                 val =  (zv_dest)->value.dval;
             } else if(type == IS_LONG) {
                 val = (double)((zv_dest)->value.lval);
             } else if(type == IS_STRING) {
                 val = (double)atof((zv_dest)->value.str->val);
             }
         }
     }

     return val;
}
```

Any idea where's the problem? I'm not a C programmer and i'm little bit lost here.

Comment: You might want to relais this question to the Internals mailing list (http://news.php.net/group.php?group=php.internals)

Comment: Not a C dev, but if you're wanting help, you're more likely to get it if you actually say what problem you're having, what error messages you get, etc. etc.

Comment: That's actually the biggest problem - the compilation runs without any problem and after running the PHP application, the only thing I know is that the error eccurs in this function.

Comment: I am experiencing similar problems. In my case the zend_hash_exists always returns 0 even when the key shows up when you iterate the HashTable.

This could be a bug in PHP, have you managed to find out more about this?